# Summing list of lists with another list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have two lists of lists, a and b:

a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

b = [[7,8,9],[1,2,3]]

If a and b were both lists of numbers, I could just convert them to arrays and obtain the sum a+b using Python. However, it seems I am unable to do the same if a and b are lists of lists. Is there a similar method, without using for or while cicles?

*Edit* The desired result would be [[8,10,12],[5,7,9]]

Comment: What should be the desired result?

Comment: not related with your question, why dont you use numpy arrays?

Comment: also, see if this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334722/sum-for-list-of-lists

Comment: `[[i + j for i, j in zip(x, y)] for x, y in zip(a, b)]`?

Comment: "I could just convert them to arrays" - you can convert a list of lists to an array too

Comment: @AndrejKesely I've added the desired result.

Comment: @ForceBru I had tried and use it, but it only gave me errors. Retrying it seemed to solve the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

b = [[7,8,9],[1,2,3]]

a=np.array(a)
a=a.flatten()
b=np.array(b)
b=b.flatten()
c=np.add(a,b)
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
output:
a=[1 2 3 4 5 6]
b=[7 8 9 1 2 3]
c=[ 8 10 12  5  7  9]
```

after this if you want list of list you can reshape it like:

```
c=np.reshape(c,[2,3])
```

Comment: Why flatten and then reshape? You can just write `np.add(a, b)` or just `a + b` to get the desired result.

Comment: Yes that can be done after making them numpy arrays but i did not know if he wanted answer in 1d array or 2d, you can add first and then flatten if you don't want to reshape, op's choice

Comment: The OP's desired result in the question is `[[8,10,12],[5,7,9]]`, which is the same shape as the original data.

Answer (score 1):

List compression:

```
[[a + b for a, b in zip(x, y)]for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

Another way:

```
k = []
for x, y in zip(a, b):
    p = []
    for a, b in zip(x, y):
        p.append(a + b)
    k.append(p)
print(k)
```